# Why does Firebase Cloud-Function send back an error object instead of the actual data

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase

I'm testing some google cloud functions locally by making a small test application in angular and a Cloud-Function. I am trying to read the response back from the Cloud-Function when I make a post request. The cloud function then returns an error with the data inside of it instead of just the actual data. Curiously if I don't subscribe to the server's response, then I never see an error in the console, meaning it must be a setting on the cloud function itself. However, I copied and pasted the cloud function code straight from the documentation. Please help.

**TL;DR:** Http Cloud-Function returning an error instead of data, why?

Here is the code for the cloud function:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
response.status(200).send('poop');
});
```

Here is the code for the test post:

```
    test() {
    var req = this.http
        .post(
            'http://localhost:5000/merchantapi-b7b17/us-central1/helloWorld',
            JSON.stringify({ poop: 'poop' })
        )
        .subscribe(_val => {
            console.log(_val);
        });
}
```

Here is the error I get on the console:

```
HttpErrorResponse

error: {error: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "poop", text: "poop"}

headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: function}

message: "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:5000/merchantapi-b7b17/us-central1/helloWorld"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"

ok: false

status: 200

statusText: "OK"

url: "http://localhost:5000/merchantapi-b7b17/us-central1/helloWorld"

HttpErrorResponse Prototype
defaultErrorLogger — core.js:6014
handleError — core.js:6066
next — core.js:40558
(anonymous function) — core.js:35336
__tryOrUnsub — Subscriber.js:185
next — Subscriber.js:124
_next — Subscriber.js:72
next — Subscriber.js:49
next — Subject.js:39
emit — core.js:35298
run — zone-evergreen.js:124
onHandleError — core.js:39735
runTask — zone-evergreen.js:171
invokeTask — zone-evergreen.js:465
timer — zone-evergreen.js:2650
defaultErrorLogger — core.js:6014
```

As you can see the error contains the data, and I can use that, but I'd like to understand why its sending an error and how to squash it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default modern HttpClient of Angular expects a JSON response and the string 'poop' is not a valid JSON.

To fix you need to send valid JSON back to the client:

```
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.status(200).send({'message':'poop'});
});
```

Valid json:

```
{
    "message": "poop"
}
```

Comment: You are the best!